# Mapstruct: mapping of Generics

Tags: java, generics, mapstruct

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper<X extends Base_1, Y extends Base_2>{
    public X mapBase_2ToBase_1(Y obj);
}
```

I want to map an object of generic type `Y` to another object of generic type `X`. Is anything like that possible with mapstruct? Or do I have to write custom mappers for Generic mapping? When I compile the code above, I get compilation errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mapstruct.ap.util.SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.replaceTypeElementIfNecessary(SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.java:90)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.util.Executables.getAllEnclosedExecutableElements(Executables.java:189)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.model.common.Type.getAllExecutables(Type.java:395)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.model.common.Type.getSetters(Type.java:464)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.model.common.Type.getPropertyWriteAccessors(Type.java:353)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.souceMethod(BeanMappingMethod.java:93)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreationProcessor.java:345)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreationProcessor.java:143)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:114)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:73)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:193)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:173)
    at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:154)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to include what specific compilation error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/631) in our tracker to address the NPE. I am doubtful though whether we can create a proper implementation for such mapper contract. We could not tell which type should be instantiated as the result type of the method.

What's your rationale for using the type parameters in the shown ways? What implementation would you expect to be generated?

Comment: Hi, my point would be to map types with same field names without specifying a separate mapper interface for each. It is hardly possible indeed because at generation time you don't know what fields these will be. But mapping at least base class fields would be possible, wouldn't it? Then you would have a basic mapper which maps all attributes of base classes at least.